# Implementing DDD encapsulation

Tags: php, oop, domain-driven-design

I hope I am following procedure right and this question is adequate. I tried searching to no avail, so I hope I can get an answer here.

I am just starting to get into Laravel. I noted a new design method called DDD and I want to try and implement it best I can.

Say I have a users package that sits in the models folder. Would it be good practice to use a main class to access features like validating a user? This class would sit in the main directory of the package lets say and will be called User. Essentially this would encapsulate the repositories, entities and services. That way the controller that needs this data won't be polluted with a bunch of calls.

For example: To validate a user login, we call:

```
 User->validateUserLogin($username, $password);
```

Then inside `User->validateUserLogin:`

```
public function validateUserLogin($username, $password)
{
    $user_login = new User_Login_Entity($username, $password);
    // Assume the validation returns a valid User object on successful validation
    $User = User_Validation_Service->ValidateUserCredentials($user_login)
}
```

Am I going about this wrong? I know SRP is key in this and I'm not sure if I am following it well enough/or at all. Essentially my thinking is: one entry point from the controller to the model work. This is opposed to having the controller call repositories, services and entities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. You should provide access - from the controller POV - to "use-cases" that use your "model". The code that does this is generally referred to as application services. They sit between your model and controller. Now, notice when I say "use cases", what I really mean are actions that change the state of your application/system/service/whateveryourebuilding. That does not include queries or other questions that - indirectly - are queries. Those are best modelled with a very thin layer over your datastore. However ... application services can perform queries in order to complete, nothing wrong with that. It's not black and white, just different shades of grey. From the controller perspective, it pays off to make a very clear distinction between actions and queries, having it take a dependency on both the thin query layer and the application services.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! That has certainly helped in how I should layer things. I had another question: I'm essentially making a new Entity per state. 

For example: a guest to my system will get a Guest_Entity which would store browser data, IP, etc. When they attempt to log in, they're given a new Entity called User_Login_Entity which would store their username, password for that attempt. Then if they're valid, they get a full blown user Entity. Is that the best way? Or should I use one mass Entity with partial assignment?

Comment: I'm totally illiterate when it comes to PHP, so don't expect me to give you advice on that. What you're saying is that you want to track "guests" or "(anonymous) visitors" of your site and when/if they do login you want to correlate their anonymous actions to their logged in actions. That only requires a "correlation id" to my knowledge. Why not pass this "browsing-session" identifier to both the anonymous tracking and the logged in tracking? Then again, this is what the logs of your webserver are for, no?

Comment: Sorry, maybe it was a bad example. Essentially what I'm saying is - is it ideal to have an Entity for each possible state that I want to track? So there would be one for Guest, another for a User and perhaps a separate one for Admins lets say. Each aggregate root would have certain capabilities/access to methods for the rest of the system.

Comment: Hard to say. Build a model (aka a set of abstractions) that serves a purpose (solving a problem domain worth solving). There's no right/one way. If you have these roles in your app and it's valuable to track them individually then just do so.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for your help. This has helped me understand the theory behind it better. :)

Comment: Hi Yves - I wanted to comment again. Your original answer is perfect. I did a little more research and I had a good night sleep.

Having a session model layer that will use an interface to talk to the user model layer seems like an ideal approach and encourages better DDD practices.

Answer (score -2):

```
 $User = User_Validation_Service->ValidateUserCredentials($user_login)
          here is the problem ----------------------------------------^
```

there should be `;` after the statement

should be

```
  $User = User_Validation_Service->ValidateUserCredentials($user_login);
```

Comment: Thanks for your catch. I am only speaking abstractly. I was making this up as I typed it to better explain what I'm trying to do. Thank-you though.